# UITapGestureRecognizer won't work in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled that contains two view controllers: vc0, vc1. The scrollview is contained in a UIView (called "dummyView"), which is contained in its own view controller.

The issue is that vc1 does not respond to touches when the view controller that contains the scrollview is set to the initial view controller. If vc1 is set to the initial view controller however, vc1 responds to touch events just fine

Why does vc1 not respond to touches when it is viewed through the scrollView?

I have included the viewdidLoad() of the view controller that contains the scrollview, where I set up the scrollview and all of its subviews.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var dummyView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 2, self.view.frame.height);
    dummyView.frame.size = scrollView.contentSize

    createConstraintsForDummyView()

    let vc0 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc0") as! ViewController0

    self.addChildViewController(vc0)
    self.dummyView.addSubview(vc0.view)
    vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    createConstraintsForVC0(vc0)

    let vc1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc1")

    var frame1 = vc1!.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1!.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc1!)
    self.dummyView.addSubview(vc1!.view)
    vc1!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    createConstraintsForVC1(vc1)     
}
```

**EDIT:** I've included the class for vc1

```
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("Tapped!")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    tap.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Where and how to you add the TapRec

Comment: I added it directly to vc0.view. I did it programatically in vc1's viewDidLoad(). But even the touchesBegan() for vc0 isn't working

Comment: Is the viewDidLoad of vc0 getting called.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that vc1 isn't being responsive to touches and taps. vc0 however is being responsive. the viewDidLoad of both vc0 and vc1 are being called

Comment: I'm not sure why only the first "page" of the scrollview can detect touches

Comment: What do you mean with "first page"

Comment: The scrollview is set up such that the user can swipe between vc0 and vc1 by swiping left or right, where the "left" page or "first" page is vc0. The code I gave in the question, shows how I did it.

Comment: Keep in mind that one tab View Controller can only recognize taps in 1 view. Can you add the code where you add the TapRec.

Comment: Use the new Swift syntax for selectors: #selector(handleTap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113085/discussion-between-123flo321-and-lahav)

The `dummyView` was causing problems. 
The solution is to remove the `dummyView` and use the `scrollView` instead.